# Logitech cordless mouse problem

Tags: mouse, logitech

I recently purchased a new Toshiba laptop and a Logitech M510 cordless
mouse.  I am running Mint 13 on the laptop.

Initially (at least once) the mouse worked fine.  Then it ceased to work.
I've seached around on various fora and found reports of similar problems
and various suggested solutions.  One of the solutions was to switch the
mouse off and remove the dongle from the laptop before booting.  Then
log in.  The wait (at least) 10 seconds before switching on the mouse
and plugging in the dongle.

This seems to work *most* of the time, but has failed to work at least
once.

I have seen a posting (David Gatrell, 2012-06-23) to the effect that

"This is really more a duplicate of bug #958174, which is still open."

But as far as I can discern there has been no "activity" on this bug
since the given date.  And I'm not sure that this applies to Mint 13
(or only to "real" Ubuntu (12.04? 12.10?).

Has anyone any ideas as to how I can get reliable performance out
of this cordless mouse?

Comment: Oops, you shouldn't have mentioned Mint :) It's off-topic here. Maybe try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?